# Python loop optimization involving the element-wise product of a 2D array and a repeated 1D array

Tags: python, numpy

Does exist a numpy function or anything else when one wants to optimize a loop like this one?

```
for i in range(0,n):
  a[i, 0:p] = b[i, 0:p] * c[0:p]
```

Here, c[0:p] is a 1D array (independent of i index) which could be stored for once before the loop to save some computing. However, I am more interested in knowing if there exists a function which could replace the for-loop itself which is quite slow.

Comment: have you tried numpy.dot?

Comment: I do not see how to use numpy.dot here since there is no sum to compute. Could you explain your idea?

Comment: Oh, I see. So you just want to do element-wise multiplication of two 1d arrays to get the output stored in 3rd?

Comment: To be clearer, the operation involved here is the element-wise product of a matrix b and another matrix which contains a vector c in each of its columns, i.e. [c, c, c, ..., c]. I think I could optimize the code by storing this last matrix and just write a = b * [c, c, ..., c] but I wonder if there exists a better solution as this one requires an extra storage cost.

Comment: Yes GOVIND, this is just an element-wise multiplication.

Comment: If all the elements of vector c are equal, you can just use a scalar in place of it. Rather than storing it in a vector. It will save some space. I guess

Comment: Unfortunately, c is not constant. I am sorry I would like to say that c is constant with respect to loop indices. I have modified the terminology to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: With broadcasting, `a=b*c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop may not be necessary as you have pointed out.

```py
assert (c[0:p]).shape == (p,)
```

and where

```py
assert (a[0:n, 0:p]).shape == (n, p)
assert (b[0:n, 0:p]).shape == (n, p)
```

You can perform a matrix multiplication and assignment directly in place of the loop:

```py
a[0:n, 0:p] = b[0:n, 0:p] * c[0:p]
```